# Swing autocomplete for large, expensive datasets

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement autocomplete for a Swing `JTextField` where the set of possible autocomplete entries can be large (10-100K items) and expensive to retrieve, but searching the set of entries is reasonably cheap. Can anyone point me to a good solution for this, preferably in library form? I looked at [SwingX autocomplete](http://www.jdocs.com/swingx/1.0/org/jdesktop/swingx/autocomplete/), but it's not designed for a situation where you don't have indexed access.

---

**Update:** Since apparently it's not clear, the problem is not that searching a large set of entries is expensive (it's not), it's that **getting** the complete set of entries, in this particular case, is expensive and impractical.

Comment: array should be sorted and comparator engine will be start after 3rd chars is typed then matches are reduced to minimum

Comment: that's not the issue, the issue is that I don't have direct access to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding Samuel Sjöberg's "[Autocompletion in Swing](http://samuelsjoberg.com/archive/2009/10/autocompletion-in-swing)" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447247/27358) and implementing the following solution, loosely based on it.

```
public class MyAutocompleteDocument extends DefaultStyledDocument {

  @Override
  public void insertString ( int offs, String str, AttributeSet a ) throws BadLocationException
  {
    if ( !StringUtils.isBlank( str ) )
    {
        String text = getText( 0, offs ); // Current text up to insert point
        String completion = complete( text + str ); // Full completed string

        if (!StringUtils.isBlank( completion )) { // not "" or null
            String textToInsert = completion.substring( offs );

            // Always overwrite on complete
            int oldLength = getLength();
            remove( offs, oldLength - offs );
            super.insertString( offs, textToInsert, a );

            // Select the auto-completed portion so it's easy to keep typing
            owner.select( offs + str.length(), getLength() );
        } else {
            super.insertString( offs, str, a );
        }
    }
  }

  private String complete(String startsWith) {
      // access service to search for completion
  }
}
```

Not sure it works in all cases but it seems to cover mine.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/). This is assuming you can load your whole data set in memory and keep it there.  I've done it with 20K items or so.

Comment: As I said, I can't load the whole data set in memory. If I could, I'd just use SwingX.

Comment: to OP use [Embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database) +1 for answer to whatever that isn't  important for programming in year 2013

Comment: @mKorbel The data's behind a service and it is MASSIVE OVERKILL to transfer it all to the client when there's a perfectly good matching API. I am NOT ASKING for an efficient way to store the data on the client, so please stop offering them.

Comment: if data's behind a service supporting pagination use that, btw without important details isn't this question answerable at all